# Facebook sdk to access friend's birthday

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please give an example code of how to access data of a user's friends, specifically birthday through Facebook SDK. All to be done using Android Studio complete with Facebook login.

I am new to android development. This particular project is based on integration of android and facebook. It requires a login and then an access to the user's friend's birthday.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response){
                        Log.v("LoginActivity",response.toString());

                        String email = object.getString("email");
                        String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public MainActivityFragment() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            // Set the access token using
            // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            displayMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null){
        textView.setText(profile.getName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access the birthday of user friends. It is not even possible to access all user friends anymore. You can only get access to friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too. If you want to get their birthdays, they have to authorize your App with the `user_birthday` permission.

In other words, you can only get birthdays of users who authorized your app with the `user_friends` and the `user_birthday` permission. This would be the API endpoint: `/me/friends?fields=name,birthday`